# jQuery hover: using .fadeIn/.fadeOut with .rotate — multiple mouseover/outs creates dodgy animation

Tags: jquery, rotation, fadein, fadeout

This is my first time posting here, and I'm fairly new to jQuery.

I have a div on my page (`.container`) that I want to rotate and fade in when I hover over another (`#containerHover`).

I'm using [jQueryRotate3.js](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/source/browse/trunk/jQueryRotate3.js?spec=svn95&r=86)
and the animation does what I want it to, fades in whilst rotating on hover, and fades out whilst rotating back on `mouseleave`.

I'm also using [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

I'm having two problems:

- Firstly, if the user enters over `#containerHover` and leaves before the animation has finished, it gives strange animations, especially when re-entered. I've read a lot about how to stop this problem if you are using `.animate` — by using `.stop()` or the plugin [hoverFlow](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/), but as far as I am aware, they are for use with `.animate()` and not `.fadeIn/.fadeOut`, or the `jQueryRotate3` plugin. I've tried changing `.fadeIn()/.fadeOut()` to `.animate ({opacity: 0} 1500)`, but I couldn't get this to work at all (which may be my fault for not being very good at jQuery).
- Secondly, it seems to also fire the `.fadeIn()/.fadeOut()` and `.rotate()` animation when hovering on `.container`, which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance for any help, and here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".container").hide();
     $(".containerHover").hoverIntent(function(){
         $(".container").fadeIn(2000) .rotate({duration:1500, angle: 270, animateTo:0});
     },
     function(){
         $(".container").fadeOut(1500) .rotate({duration:3000, angle: 0, animateTo:180});
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok… after much dicking around, this is how I fixed the first problem…

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".container").hide();

  $(".containerHover").rotate({
      bind:
{
 mouseover : function(){
    $(".container").stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000)  .rotate({duration:1500, angle: 180, animateTo:0}) 
    },
 mouseout : function(){
    $(".container").fadeOut(1200)  .rotate({duration:1500, angle: 0, animateTo:180}) 
  }
}
});
});
```

As for the second problem, I never managed to stop .container firing the animation, so made a new div with no content, the same size as .container, and placed it over the top with a higher Z-index.